# Why isnt my Vuex modules working? [vuex] unknown mutation type: moduleName/mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have been searching for hours and i can't understand why i'm getting this error:
[vuex] unknown mutation type: groceryStore/getStoreApple on all of the commits to the mutations in the groceryStore-module.
As far as i can see i'm doing it by the book. Please help if you have any idea on what i'm doing wrong when i'm trying to reach my functions in the groceryStore-module.

This is my index.js:
located in src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import * as groceryStore from "./modules/groceries";
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
   groceryStore: groceries,
  }
});
```

here is the module i'm trying to access:
src/store/modules/groceries.js

```
import { db } from "../../main";
const groceryStore = {
  namespace: true,
  state: {
    fruit: {},
    fish: {},
    meat: {},
    sauce: {},
    spices: {},
    vegetables: {},
    bakery: {},
    beverages: {},
  },
  mutations: {
    getStoreApple(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("Fruits")
        .child("Apple")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.fruit = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreFish(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("fish")
        .child("salmon")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.fish = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreMeat(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("meat")
        .child("chicken")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.meat = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreSauce(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("sauce")
        .child("mustard")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.sauce = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreSpices(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("spices")
        .child("chillipowder")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.spices = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreVegetables(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("vegtables")
        .child("carrot")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.vegetables = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreBakery(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("bakery")
        .child("bread")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.bakery = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
    getStoreBeverages(state) {
      db.ref()
        .child("groceries")
        .child("beverages")
        .child("juices")
        .get()
        .then((usersObject) => {
          state.beverages = usersObject.val();
        });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    appleGetter(state) {
      return state.fruit;
    },
    fishGetter(state) {
      return state.fish;
    },
    meatGetter(state) {
      return state.meat;
    },
    sauceGetter(state) {
      return state.sauce;
    },
    spicesGetter(state) {
      return state.spices;
    },
    vegetablesGetter(state) {
      return state.vegetables;
    },
    bakeryGetter(state) {
      return state.bakery;
    },
    beveragesGetter(state) {
      return state.beverages;
    },
  },
};

export default groceryStore;
```

And this is the component where i try to render the code:
src/views/Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1 v-if="route">This is a {{ route }} page</h1>
    <div id="flexContainer">
      <div
        class="groceryNameContainer"
        v-for="grocery in groceries"
        :key="grocery.id"
      >
        <b-card
          title=""
          img-alt="Image"
          img-top
          tag="article"
          style="max-width: 20rem;"
          class="mb-2"
          ><b-card-img v-if="grocery.url" :src="grocery.url"></b-card-img>
          <b-card-text>
            {{ grocery.description }}
          </b-card-text>
          <b-card-text>
            {{ grocery.price }}
          </b-card-text>
          <b-card-text>
            {{ grocery.comparison }}
          </b-card-text>

          <b-button href="#" variant="primary">Add to Cart</b-button>
        </b-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import { db } from "../main";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      route: "",
    };
  },

  computed: {
    groceries: function() {
      var groceriesArray = [];
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/appleGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/fishGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/meatGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/sauceGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/spicesGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/vegetablesGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/bakeryGetter"]);
      groceriesArray.push(this.$store.getters["groceryStore/beveragesGetter"]);
      console.log(groceriesArray);
      return groceriesArray;
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreApple");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreFish");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreMeat");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreSauce");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreSpices");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreVegetables");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreBakery");
    this.$store.commit("groceryStore/getStoreBeverages");

    this.route = this.$route.name;
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.nestedGroceryInfoContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.descriptionContainer {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-top: 200;
  color: rgb(6, 6, 43);
}

.nav-text-collapse {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
}
.nameContainer {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.priceContainer {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 13%;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.groceryNameContainer > * {
  flex-basis: 45%;
}

#flexContainer {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.innerProductContainer {
  margin-left: 28%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -65%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 46%;
}
.productImage {
  margin-left: 55px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 160px;
}
.detailsContainer {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.comparisonContainer {
  color: #2f2626;
}
</style>
```

Here's also the main.js file:

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import Vue from "vue";



Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: I am experienced with Vuex, but haven't used modules yet.  However, after taking a quick look at the documentation, you seem to be missing the Vuex 'modules' property: ```new Vuex.Store({ modules: { a: moduleA } })```

Comment: That's a good point, but it didnt fix anything i'm afraid. Still getting the same error :(

Comment: I see you have added `Vue.use(Vuex)` , but I don't see if you actually added the **store** on the Vue instance. (e.g.: in your `main.js` file where you would have `new Vue({ el:"#app", store: store})`

Comment: If you are still having a problem, I recommend taking modules out of the equation temporarily.  Just build your Vuex store in one file with no namespacing.  Once that is working, you can add modules/namespacing back in and see if it breaks again.

Comment: hehe @Tim, thats pretty much exactly what i've done i'm affraid. When it's all in an Index.js inside the router-folder it works like a charm.

Comment: @CatalinHoha i added the main.js file so you can see that store is added to the vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

After we exchanged a few comments, I did some digging and found a fairly simple Vuex Module example that I had built recently.  I am posting the store, module, and component here.

Your application is obviously much more complex, but one thing I noticed is that in your Vuex store you coded your module import as

```
import * as groceryStore from "./modules/groceries";
```

whereas in my store I coded the module import as

```
import userModule from './modules/user-store-module.js'
```

I'm not a JavaScript modules expert, but figured I would point it out.  Here are my source files:

**EDIT:** I added in namespacing, getters, mutations, and additional component functionality to use them.

/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import userModule from './modules/user-store-module.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    userModule: userModule
  }
})
```

/store/modules/user-store-module.js

```
const userModule = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'User1',
        gender: 'male'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'User2',
        gender: 'female'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'User3',
        gender: 'male'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'User4',
        gender: 'female'
      },
    ]
  }),
  getters: {
    getMaleUsers: state => {
      return state.users.filter( user => user.gender === 'male')
    },
    getFemaleUsers: state => {
      return state.users.filter( user => user.gender === 'female')
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    addUser(state, newGender) {
      let nextId = state.users.length + 1;
      state.users.push({
        id: nextId,
        name: 'User' + nextId,
        gender: newGender
      })
    }
  }
}

export default userModule;
```

VuexModule.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="vuex-module">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Users</h4>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>GENDER</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="addUser">Add Random User</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>Male Users</h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>NAME</th>
                  <th>GENDER</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in maleUsers" :key="user.id">
                  <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>Female Users</h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>NAME</th>
                  <th>GENDER</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in femaleUsers" :key="user.id">
                  <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        gender: 'male'
      }
    },
    computed: {
      users() {
        return this.$store.state.userModule.users;
      },
      maleUsers() {
        return this.$store.getters['userModule/getMaleUsers'];
      },
      femaleUsers() {
        return this.$store.getters['userModule/getFemaleUsers'];
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addUser() {
        let nextGender = this.gender === 'male' ? 'female' : 'male';
        this.gender = nextGender;
        this.$store.commit('userModule/addUser', this.gender);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It all looks great, its just that i cant seem to find what i'm doing different... I'm wondering if it can have something to do with me using Vue 2x?

Comment: I think that I may have found the problem.  Looking at your 'src/store/index.js' file in your question, your import is ```import * as groceryStore from "./modules/groceries";```, but in ```new Vuex.Store()```, you wrote ```modules: { groceryStore: groceries, }```.  I think it should be ```modules: { groceryStore: groceryStore, }``` (NOT groceries), or even shortened to ```modules: { groceryStore }```.  Let me know if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as groceryStore from "./modules/groceries";
```

will give you an object of all the export from the file.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents)

In your case it will probably give you an object

```
 {
     default: {}// your groceries object
    }
```

so please try

```
 import groceryStore from "./modules/groceries";
```